# BASH scripts for generating inputs to parallel C++ jobs

Tags: c++, bash, shell, scripting

I'm an amateur C++ programmer trying to learn about basic shell scripting. I have a complex C++ program that currently reads in different parameter values from `Parameters.h` and then executes one or more simulations with each parameter value sequentially. These simulations take a long time to run. Since I have a cluster available, I'd like to effectively parallelize this job, running the simulations for each parameter value on a separate processor. I'm assuming it's easier to learn shell scripting techniques for this purpose than OpenMPI. My cluster runs on the LSF platform.

How can I write my input parameters in Bash so that they are distributed among multiple processors, each executing the program with that value? I'd like to avoid interactive submission. Ideally, I'd have the inputs in a text file that Bash reads, and I'd be passing two parameters to each job: an actual parameter value and a parameter ID.

Thanks in advance for any leads and suggestions.

---

**my solution**

GNU Parallel does look slick, but I ended up (with the help of an IT admin) writing a simple bash script that echos to screen three inputs (a treatment identifier, treatment/parameter value, and a simulation identifier):

```
#!/bin/bash 
j=1
for treatment in cat treatments.txt; do
  for experiment in cat simulations.txt; do
   bsub -oo tr_${j}_sim_${experiment}_screen -eo tr_${j}_sim_${experiment}_err -q short_serial "echo \"$j $treatment $experiment\" | ./a.out"
  done
  let j=$j+1 
done
```

The file `treatments.txt` contains a list of the values I'd like to vary, `simulations.txt` contains a list of all the simulation identifiers I'd like to run (currently just 1,...,s, where s is the total number of simulations I want for each treatment), and the treatments are indexed 1...`j`.

Comment: Does having a `Parameters.h` file mean that the input values are hard-coded and compiled in the executable? Or does you program parse that file at runtime?

Comment: Currently, the input values are hard-coded as const double TREATMENTS[ NUM_TREATMENTS ] = { ... };, but I could of course read them in as inputs during runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you want to run the program `simulate` with inputs `foo`, `bar`, `baz` and `quux` in parallel, then the simplest way is:

```
inputs="foo bar baz quux"

# Launch processes in the background with &
children=""
for x in $inputs; do
    simulate "$x" > "$x.output" &
    $children = "$children $!"
done

# Wait for each to finish
for $pid in $children; do
    wait $pid
done

for x in $inputs; do
    echo "simulate '$x' gave:"
    cat "$x.output"
    rm -f "$x.output"
done
```

The problem is that all simulations are launched at the same time, so if your number of inputs is much larger than your number of CPUs/cores, they may swamp the system.

Comment: Thanks--I ended up doing something similar to this with my bash script. Have pasted my script above.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe check out: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/

edit:

Or, check out the -P argument to xargs, example:

```
time echo {1..5} | xargs -n 1 -P 5 sleep
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm following up with the cluster admins to see if it can be supported and am starting the tutorials. I'll accept this answer in a bit if things pan out (at least in theory).

Answer (score 0):

My best stab at this is you background multiple instances of your program and let the OS's scheduler take over to put them on different processors.  AFAIK there is no way in any shell to specify which processor a given process should run on.

Something to the effect of:

```
#!/bin/sh

for arg in foo bar baz; do
   ./your_program "$arg" &
done
```

Comment: Will this work in an OpenMPI cluster? Your code assumes that the kernel is aware of the cluster and can migrate processes accordingly. I thought only MOSIX supported something like that.

Comment: @thkala yes to the assumption. I have no exp with clusters.